# Who is the man in a car talking to Dry Eye?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-gentlemen

In *The Gentlemen*, Dry Eye, an underboss working for Lord George, goes behind Lord George's back, cuts a deal with Matthew, tries to undermine Mickey's business.

Dry Eye murders Lord George and betrays Matthew later in the movie, and Dry Eye is seen talking to someone in a car. While talking to this person, Dry Eye shows great respect.

- This unknown person encourages Dry Eye to be aggressive and take over the illegal drug trade for his own.

Who is this person?